# c# DataSet.WriteXml(fileStream, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema); corrupts my xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, filestream

```
<Data>
  <configs>
    <someEntry>"value1"</someEntry>
  </configs>
  <profiles>
    <someEntry>"value2"</someEntry>
  </profiles>
</Data>es>
    <someEntry>"value3"</someEntry>
  </profiles>
</Data>
```

That `</Data>es>` is the problem.
It happens when I try to delete the "value3" DataRow in this example. The DataTable Visualizer of Visual Studio shows that my table is fine but the DataSet gets saved that way although it's suppossed to be this way:

```
<Data>
  <configs>
    <someEntry>"value1"</someEntry>
  </configs>
  <profiles>
    <someEntry>"value2"</someEntry>
  </profiles>
</Data>
```

Before starting using FileStream everything worked as expected. This is how I initiate my FileStream:

```
FileStream filestream = new FileStream(xmlLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `FileMode.Open`, which doesn't truncate the file if it already exists.

Just use `File.Create` instead:

```
using (var stream = File.Create(directory))
{
    ...
}
```

(You *could* specify `FileMode.Create` instead, as your post originally had before you edited it, but I find it much simpler to call the `File.*` simplified methods in almost all cases.)

Comment: Actually my FileStream is a global object, so I can't do it with `using` and there is also one more stream which is only responsible for the file creation and then it gets disposed.

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΕπανωμή: That sounds like a bad idea to me, to be honest - if the same stream could be used all over your code, that's going to make it much harder to handle it properly. But fundamentally the point is that you want to make sure that when you rewrite the file, you truncate any current content.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will try this tomorow and I'll post back.